# Table is not splitting in the right way

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset and code:

```
options nocenter; 
DATA survey; 
 INPUT product_id department; 
 DATALINES; 
  1212 Sales
  1213 Sales
  1214 Marketing
 ; 
 PROC PRINT; RUN;

data sales marketing;
set survey;
 if department = 'Sales' then output sales;
 else if department = 'Marketing' then output marketing;
 run;

title 'Sales employees';
 proc print data= sales;
 run;
 title;

title 'Marketing employees';
 proc print data= marketing;
 run;
 title;
```

This however gives me two tables with all the values while I only a table with the marketing- and sales values. Also the title appears above the second table but not above the first. Any thoughts what goes wrong?

Comment: Check your log for errors. Your code to split the dataset looks fine. But as written your first DATA step should error because is should expect the Department variable to be numeric.  Do you see errors in the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a `'$'` sign after your variable `'department'`, so you get the `'.'` for missing (numeric) values. In addition to that the variable is truncating my value of `Marketing` to `Marketin`, so the data set `Marketing` never finds a string that equals `'Marketing'`, so your input should be `INPUT product_id department $10.;` . The title statements work of for me.